# Data Table and List

Tags: web-app, lists, mobile-web, data-tables, dynamic-ui

Hope you all are safe.

I am designing a selection list for one of the requirement in my project. Preferably, like shown below

[image]

I wanted to know what is the difference between List and Data table to achieve this.
Anything in particular that there are some limitations that I need to consider about? Feel free to shoot the answer directly.

**Please note: The interaction with user is only selection and unselect.**

Answer (score 1):

There doesn’t seem to be a need for columns data to compare so would definitely avoid a table here.

The only advantage of a table I can think of in this case is that you can put the checkbox and label into columns. But you can do that with CSS easily.

I’d avoid tables because they’re harder for some users to operate – like screen reader users or on small screens.